# KDE systemsettings left panel option pop on right

Tags: kde

I'm try to change appearance on kde.Then I don't know why my settings include options pop on right

expect:

(use 'discover' on kde and select first option on left panel)

[image]

should be like this

[image]

reality:

(use 'systemsettings' on kde and select first option on left panel)

[image]

How can I back to default.

Comment: Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04,
KDE Plasma 5.25.5

Comment: 22.04 uses Plasma 5.24.7, seems you installed your version of Plasma not from official sources. I can't even switch to this view in System Settings, there is not such an option. Usually there are some configuration options offered when you click the hamburger icon right next to the search bar. Perhaps this is the default view in Plasma 5.25.2.

Comment: I review many times that I even couldn't find any setting about that.btw,I've install official plasma from apt

Comment: I have been seen this before.the only solution I tried is fully remove plasma workspace then reinstall it.until now,I still don't know how to solve the problem

Comment: Plasma version 5.25.2 is used in Ubuntu 22.10, not 22.04. Please make sure that you provide correct details. If you are using 22.10 you should upgrade to 23.04 as soon as possible, 22.10 reached End of Life last month and is not supported anymore.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/07/27/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-end-of-life-reached-on-july-20-2023/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades   If using KDE Neon; it's not Ubuntu, using only a Ubuntu base (parts would be 22.04) & parts from later non-LTS releases such as 22.10, 23.04 to get newer Qt5, KF5 & thus KDE Plasma, also off-topic here

Comment: Thanks your suggests.when I startup my ubuntu today.the settings panel back to normal.(but why?)

Comment: Most likely it's a bug you experience. Either use 22.04 with Plasma 5.24.7 or use 23.04 with Plasma 4:5.27.4.